# How to stop beep sound in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

How I have done a continues beep notification:

```
function onDeviceReady()
        {
            navigator.vibrate([2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000]);
            navigator.notification.beep(10);
        }
```

How I was trying to stop that:

```
function onDeviceReady()
   {
       navigator.vibrate(0);
       navigator.notification.beep(0);
   }
```

But it's not stopping, it's still continuously ringing, how to stop it?

Comment: Its better to invoke one beep at a time within loop and have a global variable to control it rather than beeping 10 times at one shot. Setting beep(0) wont resolve the prob. Something like this should do: var beepstop = false;
var inter = setInterval(function(){
   if(!beepstop)navigator.notification.beep(1);   
},5000);

function stopBeep(){ beepstop = true; }

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @Gandhi bro sorry i forget ,your answer work like a charm

Comment: pls post it  as answer might be help some one

Comment: Bro do keep us informed, that's what motivates us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to invoke one beep at a time within loop and have a global variable to control it rather than beeping 10 times at one shot. Setting beep(0) won't resolve the prob.

This code should do the trick:

```
var beepstop = false;
var inter = setInterval(
    function() {
        if (!beepstop) navigator.notification.beep(1);
    }, 5000);

function stopBeep() {
    beepstop = true;
}
```